# Best way to display formatted code in android studio (indented and coloured etc.)

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

I'm developing an app in android studio which requires me to display alot of sample codes, particularly in Kotlin. It's basically an app to teach users the basics of Kotlin. Hence, there will be a need to display sample codes. What are the best and easiest ways to implement this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you can create gist samples directly from intelij (android-studio)...

[Create GitHub Gists from IDE](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2011/09/github-gists-are-here/)

Answer (score 1):

A third-party library like [Codeview-Android](https://github.com/kbiakov/CodeView-android) is probably the easiest way to handle this.

Comment: Good suggestion but it does not offer kotlin as a language, closest is Java sadly ..